# Server Control in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am create MVC 4 Application, using aspx view engine.

My Question is :

I read some material, that there is no viewstate and postback concept in ASP.MVC. Why I can use server control in my view?

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have read correctly - there is no such thing as ViewState and Postback in MVC. If you really need to use a specific ASP.NET server control, you have to add a standard WebForms page to your project and place the server control inside it.

You might need to alter the routes table (usually in App_Start\RouteConfig.cs) and add an exception for the route to the WebForms page.